# conservar todos los registros por cada llamada AJAX en VB.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

Envió a través de AJAX valores según los checkbox que seleccione un usuario a otra pagina2 que los recibe, y los procesa a una BD, el problema es que tengo un ciclo each con jquery para el envio del valor que seleccionó el usuario y si el usuario selecciona 3 ckeck la pagina2 se llama 3 veces para enviar el valor del check, cada ves que se llama la pagina2 dibujo una tabla HTML para colocar los valores que corresponden al valor del check que se seleccionó, ¿Como puedo conservar los valores que se dibujan en la tabla html de cada llamada a la pagina2? ya que si se seleccionan 3 checkbox la tabla se dibuja una vez aparecen datos y desaparece, después la segunda vez aparecen datos y desaparece, y por ultimo la tercera vez aparecen datos y se muestran los datos de esta ultima, lo que requiero es que aparezcan las 3 tablas

```js
    $("#btnEnviar").click(function () {        
        var selected = '';
        var varValorCheck = '';
        $("#form1 input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                selected += $(this).val() + ', ';
                varValorCheck = $(this).val()
                //alert(varValorCheck);
                EnviarReporte(varValorCheck,selected);
            }
        });

        if (selected == '')

            alert('Debes seleccionar al menos una opción.');

        return false;
    });
```

```js
    function EnviarReporte(varValorCheck, varAcumulador) {
      
      var facturaSeleccionada = varValorCheck
      var acumuladorFact = varAcumulador


      var cargando = $("#muestraSeccion").html("<center><img  src='../Images/cargando1.gif' height='50px' width='50px'/><br/>Un momento por favor...<center>");

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'guardarEnvio',
        data: {
          "facturaEnvio": facturaSeleccionada,
          "acumuladorFactura": acumuladorFact
        },
        success: function(resultado) {

          $("#muestraSeccion").hide().html(resultado).fadeIn("fast");


        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
          if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

            alert('Not connect: Verify Network.=(');

          } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

            alert('Requested page not found [404].');

          } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

            alert('Error Interno del Servidor [500].');

          } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {

            alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');

          } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {

            alert('Time out error.');

          } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {

            alert('Ajax request aborted.');

          } else {

            alert('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);

          }

        }
      });
    }
```

```html
@Code
    PageData("Title") = "Escriba el título aquí"
    
    Dim db = Database.Open("empresaFactura")
    Dim factura = Request.Form("facturaEnvio")
    Dim acumulador = Request.Form("acumuladorFactura")
    Dim fecha = DateTime.Now().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

    
    Dim verFactura As New funciones()
    Dim resgistrosFactura = verFactura.DatosFacturaEnvio(factura)
        
    Dim cuerpoCorreo As String
    
    cuerpoCorreo = "<table style='border-color: #666;margin: 0 auto;' cellpadding='10' >" & _
              "<tr style='background: #eee;'><thead> <td><strong>Factura</strong></td> <td><strong>Fecha<strong></td> </thead></tr>"
    
    
    For Each item2 In resgistrosFactura
        cuerpoCorreo += "<tr> <td>" & item2.nombre & "</td> <td>" & item2.ap & "</td> <td>" & item2.am & "</td> </tr>"
    Next
    
    
    
    cuerpoCorreo += "</table>"
        
    Response.Write(cuerpoCorreo)

End Code
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has intentado guardando los valores en localstorage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Habia implementado algo relacionado a lo que planteas conservando los datos seleccionado o ingresado valores en la tabla

[[GridView] Mantener checkbox durante la paginación](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2012/02/gridview-mantener-checkbox-durante-la.html)

[[ASP.NET] Mantener información al cambiar de pagina](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2012/02/aspnet-mantener-informacion-al-cambiar.html)

La idea es conservar los datos del lado del servidor y unirlos a los nuevos cuando navegas de una pagina a otra.

Analiza los articulos y veras que puedes en el servidor margear los datos y enviar las marcas que tenias previamente cuando vuelvas a la pagina anterior.

Lo que planteo implica mantener los datos del lado del servidor, trabajarlos desde alli y enviarlos a la UI como respuesta del json, para acceder a la session desde un `WebMethod` seguro debas usar el `HttpContext.Current`